# How to find out if a game is a demo or not on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

In My Games and Apps on the Xbox One, how do I find out if one of the games listed is a demo or not? I think I have a few demos in my library, I cannot figure out if it is though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most games that are demos have the word demo in their title.  For instance, Dead Rising 3 has a demo titled "Dead Rising 3 Demo" in the store and it will be titled that way as well in your My Games and Apps section.  LEGO Jurassic World has a demo that is also titled LEGO Jurassic World Demo.

In the case of Dead Rising 3's demo, the cover art for the app tile also says "Demo" on it in the artwork.

There is no fast way to really tell if a game is a demo.  If you want, you can press the start button on a game tile, select "Go to game hub" and read the description which sometimes states if it is a demo, but not always.

You can also get a good idea if it is a demo or not by seeing how big the game is.  The LEGO game mentioned is around 14.6Gb while the demo was only 1.6Gb.  Dead Rising 3's demo was around 7Gb while the actual game is around 26.9Gb.  This isn't the most accurate method however, as I believe some games you can download the whole game as a demo and unlock the full game without having to download it.

Comment: "There is no fast way to really tell if a game is a demo."  - One of the biggest gripes I have about XB's marketplace. Instead of doing a demo or if a demo isn't available, I usually look on twitch (launched from the gamehub under that game) and watch someone play the game for a bit to see if I would like it.